# Problems at redirecting specific pages in Tumblr

Tags: javascript, html, css, tumblr

What I need to do is redirect my main [tumblr blog](http://no-poo-es.tumblr.com/) to a static homepage. 
So that when someone goes to my blog is redirected to the static homepage instead of all the posts.

The process of redirecting might seem like making it harder than it needs to be, but other solutions have not worked. I was able to do the static homepage by changing other parts of the code (without the need of redirecting pages) but it made all the posts disappear, even when looking at their tags. (See more detail into this solution I tried in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33468797/posts-not-showing-when-searching-tags-on-tumblr-after-making-a-static-homepage/))

So since that doesn't work, all I can think of now is to redirect my tumblr to another one to be the homepage. The new tumblr blog with the static home page is "no-poo-es-inicio.tumblr.com" and the links in the navigation bar go to the actual tumblr blog where I will be posting. (This new blog has the code that created a static homepage and hid all the posts)

To do the redirecting I have tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(location.href == 'http://no-poo-es.tumblr.com');
location.replace('http://no-poo-es-inicio.tumblr.com');
</script>
```

And it works at redirecting, but it redirects everything that starts with my blog url, meaning "no-poo-es.tumblr.com/tagged/foto" or "no-poo-es.tumblr.com/post1" are also redirected to the new url, which I dont want since the new url is only supposed to be the homepage.

I need to find a way so that only my blog url is redirected, but when it has anything added afterwards it won't redirect.

Don't know much about coding so if you have a solution that is not html or javascript, can you also tell me which code to add to install whatever needs to be installed, if even, and how to properly write it in the html code. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tumblr has help for this [here](http://support.tumblr.com/post/23625479768/how-to-make-redirect-pages).

Otherwise, I'm unsure whether Tumblr will have user-support for JS redirection.

Comment: Those redirect pages are the ones I mentioned at the end. You can't redirect your url but you can make url/home redirect to another webpage.
What I need to do is to redirect my url, not a page within it. 
I know there is no way using the tools provided by Tumblr to create a static homepage or something similar (unless the theme you are using is coded that way, can't afford those), which is why I need to change the html code to add one.

Comment: I see what you mean. In that case, I would try to accomplish an "if and only if" scenario for checking the URL. Before that, though, I think a possible error is your placing a semi-colon at the end of `if(location.href == 'http://no-poo-es.tumblr.com'); => if(location.href == 'http://no-poo-es.tumblr.com')`. Try removing that - I see what you are trying to do with the if statement but I'm thinking that the semicolon is preventing the conditional replacing of href. That is, the `location.replace` is being run _every time_ instead of only when `location.href == yourwebsite`.

Comment: I didn't know writing or not a semicolon would influence the way is read, thought writing it that way was the appropriate way to do it. Tried erasing the first one and it wouldnt redirect anything, erased the second one, just to see what would happen, and it kept redirecting everything that started with my url, just like before. Erased both, to see what would happen, and it didn't redirect anything.

Comment: In that case, could you try replacing your script with this:

`if(location.href == 'http://no-poo-es.tumblr.com/') {
     location.replace('http://no-poo-es-inicio.tumblr.com/');
}`

Comment: The problem that I am seeing is that somehow when it checks if the location is the url, it will say is true even if something after the url is placed, so I need to find a way to code it so that if it finds something after the url it won't redirect. But I don't know that much to do the code myself.

Comment: That worked! amazingly it worked. Thank you. Don't know what difference it makes but it works ajja. Thank you again.

Comment: Happy to help :) I was initially a bit confused by your question because the location.href should check whether the URL is _exactly_ what you are testing against. Nonetheless good luck with your further coding.